# 3 dimensional array as input with Embedding Layer and LSTM in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, word-embedding

Hey guys I have built an LSTM model that works and now I am trying(unsuccessfully) to add an Embedding layer as a first layer.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120817/lstm-after-embedding-of-a-n-dimensional-sequence) didn't work for me.
I also read these questions before asking:
[Keras input explanation: input_shape, units, batch_size, dim, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747343/keras-input-explanation-input-shape-units-batch-size-dim-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1),
[Understanding Keras LSTMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714959/understanding-keras-lstms) and [keras examples](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/examples).

My input is a one-hot encoding(of ones and zeros) of characters of a language that consists 27 letters. I chose to represent each word as a sequence of 10 characters. Input size for each word is `(10,27)` and I have 465 of them so it's `X_train.shape (465,10,27)`, I also have a label of size `y_train.shape (465,1)`. My goal is to train a model and while doing that to build a character embeddings.

Now this is the model that compiles and fits.

```
main_input = Input(shape=(10, 27))
rnn = Bidirectional(LSTM(5))
x = rnn(main_input)
de = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs = main_input, outputs = de)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
```

After adding Embedding layer:

```
main_input = Input(shape=(10, 27))
emb = Embedding(input_dim=2, output_dim = 10)(main_input)
rnn = Bidirectional(LSTM(5))
x = rnn(emb)
de = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs = main_input, outputs = de)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
```

> output: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer bidirectional_31:  expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

How do I fix the output shape?
Your ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I commented below

Answer (score 4):

> My input is a one-hot encoding(of ones and zeros) of characters of a language that consists 27 letters.

You shouldn't pass a one-hot-encoding into an `Embedding`. `Embedding` layers map an integer index to an n-dimensional vector. As a result you should pass in the pre-one-hotted indexes directly.

I.e. before you have an one-hotted input like `[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]`, which was created from a set of integers like `[1, 0, 2]`. Instead of passing on the `(10, 27)` one-hotted vector pass in original vector of `(10,)`.

```
main_input = Input(shape=(10,)) # only pass in the indexes
emb = Embedding(input_dim=27, output_dim = 10)(main_input) # vocab size is 27
rnn = Bidirectional(LSTM(5))
x = rnn(emb)
de = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs = main_input, outputs = de)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
```

Comment: The problem is that there is no ‘original vector’ because every character gets a one-hot coding. So for example, a character ‘a’ would have first number ‘1’ in vector and all the others are zeroes. And this is the way it is done with characters in NLP, as far as I know.

Comment: Yes so you directly do a -> 1, b -> 2, c ->3 instead of the onehot encoding, your array will look like [1, 2, 3] for "abc" instead of the one hotted version. This is repeated and elaborate more upon in my answer.